# Comparing two sets of proportions/percentages from related samples (bibliometrics, qualitative data)

Tags: nonparametric, qualitative

I'm a newbie in statistics and bibliometrics, so I'm quite lost right now. I have two sets of data, A and B, both of them with frequencies of topics or subjects used in translation research publications. Set A (audiovisual translation) is a subset of B (all translation-related fields). I want to know whether the proportions of the topics in A are similar or not to those in B. As I'm dealing with qualitative data, I now know I cannot use Kendall's tau-b correlation coefficient (which I did before and works just fine, by the way). Absolute numbers are not comparable (eg. 100 / 5.000), so chi-squared test is not useful either, because I think I cannot use it with percentages. So which test should I use? Wilcoxon signed rank test?
Thanks for your help in advance and best of luck for the new year.
Paco

Answer (score 0):

When formulating hypotheses for statistical tests there is no room for vague terms like "similar". So yournull hypothesis is that the proportion of A equals the proportion of B, and since A is subset of B, it also means that the proportion on group C ( in B but *not* in A) equals 0. Is this really a hypothesis you are interested in? My suspicion is that your answer is no, in which case you don't want to do this test. If you are interested in that hypothesis, then you are in trouble since your hypothesis is on the boundary of the parameter space and everything gets harder there. If you find at least one in C, then the null cannot be true. This is different from other tests.

Comment: Thank you, Maarten. Actually, I don't quite understand why the proportion on a different group should (always) equal 0. Example: 35% of publications in A are related to subtitles, while only 2.6% in B and 0% in C (being literary translation, for example). But literature-related publications are 4.93% in A, 25.36% in B and 100% in C. What about Mann-Whitney's U?

Comment: Do not start with looking for tests. Instead start by explicitly formulating the null hypothesis you want to test. A test is not a goal in itself, but a means to test a hypothesis. Making a statement about the hypothesis is the goal. I don't see your hypothesis in your question.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear C in my definition is the complement of A within B. So the proportions you mention in your comment are impossible. It is perfectly possible such proportions exit, but the groups cannot be group C as I defined it.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. I know the proportions of A will never exactly equal B on any of the parameters I will compare (subject area, language of publication, etc.), so that's why I need some test that shows degrees of "similarity" or association, and I just hope there's one. Though I know it's not applicable, Kendall correlation was doing fine for me, because the degree of association it showed was always right. Regarding group C, I'm not interested in comparing A with the rest of B, but with the whole B.

Comment: So you do not want a test but a measure of association. That makes more sense. I suggest you edit your question to reflect that **and** exactly describe what you want (that is still not clear) and what your data looks like.